# Help on Proving Reflexive, Symmetry and Transitivity for xy>= 1, with relation r E Z , xy E integers,IF AND ONLY IF xy >= 1

Tags: relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations

My working so far that:

Reflexive: Yes
as suppose x E in r, we get x^2 >= 1 which true for all so this is true.

Symmetric:
I think it is true since xy >= 1 and xy = yx order not important?

Transitive:
suppose xy >= 1 and yz>=1 then xz>=1 must hold true ?

Im not sure if im on the right track or need more depth in m proof help appreciated.

Comment: What do "r E Z" and "x E in r" mean?

Comment: The relation r is the set of Integers x,y exist in Integers IF AND ONLY IF xy >= 1

Answer (score 1):

Just try $x=z=\frac12$, $y=4$. Btw, $x=\frac12$ or even $x=0$ will also kill refexivity.

Comment: but x, z , y must be in Integers Z

Comment: @nihaal Sorry, I could not onfer that from your question. Then still $0^2\not\ge 1$

Comment: but 0 isnt E in integers right